# Using subquery value to filter parent result but still return all child items related to parent

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have many emails storied in a database and each of those email's have a child recipient. I'm trying to write a LINQ query where I only return emails that have a recipient address LIKE some provided string but if the parent email is returned all recipients matching or not are still returned. I've built this SQL that works but my code is only filtering on the recipients and not the parent email.

What the table contains in JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "email_id": "dcfe0dfc-e4ad-4fd3-b482-61ced67a19ec",
    "recipient": [
      {
        "email_address": "someemail@someplace.com"
      },
      {
        "email_address": "someotherAddress@example.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "email_id": "f53a7681-98f8-4385-b3d2-9e9af2560664",
    "recipient": [
      {
        "email_address": "someemail@someplace.com"
      },
      {
        "email_address": "a_newAddress@example.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "email_id": "f53a7681-98f8-4385-b3d2-9e9af2560664",
    "recipient": [
      {
        "email_address": "someAddress@email.com"
      },
      {
        "email_address": "a_newAddress@example.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM email e
RIGHT JOIN recipient r on e.email_id = r.email_id
WHERE r.email_id in (SELECT email_id 
                             from recipient WHERE email_address = 'someemail@someplace.com')
Order By e.create_date desc;
```

C# LINQ statement

```
var query = _context.Email
                .IncludeFilter(x => x.Recipient.Where(r => string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.RecipientAddress) || 
                                                           EF.Functions.Like(r.EmailAddress, $"%{request.RecipientAddress}%"))).ToList();
```

Expected Output:

```json
[
    {
        "email_id": "dcfe0dfc-e4ad-4fd3-b482-61ced67a19ec",
        "recipient": [
          {
            "email_address": "someemail@someplace.com"
          },
          {
            "email_address": "someotherAddress@example.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "email_id": "f53a7681-98f8-4385-b3d2-9e9af2560664",
        "recipient": [
          {
            "email_address": "someemail@someplace.com"
          },
          {
            "email_address": "a_newAddress@example.com"
          }
        ]
      }
]
```

With the above my result returns all the emails as expected but the recipients included in each one is only the matching recipient and I expect it to return all recipients still. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide sample input and expected output

Comment: add total data example and expected result in json format.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. It was much simpler then I was giving it credit for.

```
_context.email.Where(x => xstring.IsNullOrEmpty(request.RecipientAddress) ||
    x.Recipients.Any(y => 
        EF.Functions.Like(y.Email, $"%{request.RecipientAddress}%")))
    .Include(x => x.Recipients).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreateDate).ToList();
```

Comment: you should also be able to use Email.Contains() instead of the Like function.